# 4 ядро в 12 Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, ядро

Будет ли жить 4 ядро в 12 убунте? В интернетах пока ничего внятного не накопал. Попробовал бы сам, но заткнулся на установке: оно зависит от пакета `kmod`, которого там нет и нужно собирать отдельно, который, в свою очередь, зависит от `autoreconf` и `gtkdocsize`, которые тоже нужно вытягивать... На этом этапе остановился и решил уточнить - а не впустую ли усилия?

Поясню зачем: работаю с kernel module, само собой, под виртуалкой. А там 16 убунта и так еле ворочается, даже в виде хубунты и лубунты (X нужны). Зато 12 с ядром 3.2.0 вполне летает. Но - см. выше...

Comment: вместо кубунты (которая не такая уж и легкая), я бы пробовал как минимум xubuntu (с xfce). И просто бы докупил памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim, опечатался, конечно же xubuntu. Памяти у меня под каждую витруалку по 6Gb отводится. Пробовал больше - никак на шевелючесть не влияет.

Comment: @PinkTux а гипервизор какой?

Comment: у меня на 4 гигах вполне хорошо шевелиться xfce + gentoo. Может используется только одно ядро? или под убунтой запускается 100500 сервисов, которые и тормозят? У колеги тормозило страшно, причина была в процессе, который индексировал файлы.

Comment: ядро одно, и с этим пока ничего не сделать, на хост-машине их всего два. система после установки вылизывается, ничего лишнего там бегает. использую virtualbox и vmplayer, принципиальной разницы нет. хотя vmlayer чуть шустрей, но он состояние машины сохраняет/восстанавливает заметно дольше... так что пока всё ещё пытаюсь взгромоздить 4 ядро на xubuntu 12.

Comment: то есть, у Вас два ядра и Вы надетесь, что оно  будет как то шевелится? при двух одна ось еле шевелится.

Comment: @KoVadim, 12 убунта вполне шевелится с устраивающей меня скоростью. Вопрос про установку 4 ядра на неё.

Comment: Можете хоть v4.8-rc4 поставить, но из исходников.